# Ubuntu Server 12.04 stops responding soon after assigning a static IP manually

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, dhcp, ip

I know there's a lot written about this issue but no response seem to answer my question. So I am wondering my problem is with the most recent version of Ubuntu.

I have just installed an Ubuntu 12.04 server (64bit) - Precise, on my home PC using Virtualbox v4.3.6 by Bridging the network adapter.

Everything works fine as I can run `apt-get update` and see the outside world, name resolution resolves perfectly too (i.e: nslookup google.com)

My problem is when I edit the interfaces file and enter a static address identical to the DHCP address issued by my router, and restart the server or the network, I can no longer access my local network, in other words I cannot even ping my gateway.

If I enter the same IP address manually, for example `ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.15`, I can then ping my gateway but I cannot see the outside world.

I have purged my Network Manager, wondering if that is the cause. When I installed the server at work I can work around this by reserving the IP address, but I am hoping to get a better understanding of the problem.

Any advise on this?

Thanks for your replies, this is my interface file with static assigned

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Thanks but. Adding nameserver to the interface file didn't help. When I switched back to DHCP everything works fine, I can ping internet addresses by IP and by name.

Comment: how did you set the static ip address

Comment: could you please post the output of your interfaces after assigning the static IP's... you may use `cat /etc/network/interfaces` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't mention your dns name server :

So if you `ping 173.194.41.115` which is google ip , it will ping normally , but if you ping 
**www.google.com**  it will state **unknow host** .

So in your options in `/etc/network/interfaces` add :

`dns-nameservers (your dns ip address` )

I hope this could solve your problem , reply.